# Premiere export to WMV causes aliasing

Tags: premiere

I have a clip made of a sequence of .png images, which I import to premiere. When I create a new sequence with different dimensions from that of the clip, add the clip to it and export it as a .wmv file, I see a lot of aliasing. However, when I make a sequence out of the clip (using the "New sequence from clip" option) and export it to a .wmv file, everything works great, even if I scale the clip in the sequence. In what lies the difference? The two sequences's settings only differ in their dimension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, found out the problem: the sequence's interlacing option was turned on, while I was exporting without interlacing.

Comment: Glad you found your answer.  Thanks for posting what you found rather than deleting the question.  I'm sure this could be useful to others in the future.  Also, welcome to AVP.